# Storing a HighScore in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to store a highscore in Unity. How do I get it to save the highscore?

This is what I have so far

```
private float gameTime = 0; //the time (in seconds) that the player has been playing the level

 public void PlayerWin()
{
    gameOver = true;

    //Update the highscore
    float bestTime = 0;

    bool isNewHighscore = false;

    //Pop up the win message
    UIController.GameOver(WIN_MESSAGE, gameTime, bestTime, isNewHighscore);
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to local highscores, or the same highscore table for all the players?

Answer (score 4):

You would want to use [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).  Since it appears as if you're tracking the score by the bestTime variable (a float type) you would specifically want to use [PlayerPerfs.SetFloat](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetFloat.html)

Your code would then look something like:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("highScore", bestTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

save your score using the key highScore

```
void saveHighScoreee() {
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("highScore", 10.0F);
} 

PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

this is how you get the saved score

```
void Example() {
    print(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("highScore"));
}
```

for more info please check the official doc

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Answer (score 0):

PlayerPrefs gonna save some data locally (in a special file). You can use it even if you close your executable.

Doc : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

You can manipulate **Int**, **Float** and **String**

In your case, you need normally int (for seconds) but you use float.

- If you want to save data (bestScore) : `PlayerPrefs.setFloat("BestScore", bestTime);`
- If you want to get data (bestScore) : `PlayerPrefs.getFloat("BestScore");`