# setting a high score from score and showing it in unity2D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a score in my game that increments at certain points! this is working fine but i want a saved high score and unsure how to implement playerprefs as i am still getting to grips with unity and c#! so far i have placed a ui text element in my canvas and this is called High Score: 0 i would like the 0 to hold and save the high score! the working score that increments at the moment is in the update method.
EDIT, just to point out this is not a duplicate of a link posted below! both are looking for different answers to a question that seems similar but is not

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public string currentColor;

public float jumpForce = 10f;

public Rigidbody2D circle;
public SpriteRenderer sr;

public Color blue;
public Color yellow;
public Color pink;
public Color purple;

public static int score = 0;
public Text scoreText;


public GameObject obsticle;
public GameObject colorChanger;

void Start () {

    setRandomColor ();
    circle.isKinematic = true;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 

        {
        circle.isKinematic = false;
            circle.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }

    scoreText.text = score.ToString ();

}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Scored") 
    {
        score++;
        Destroy (collision.gameObject);
        Instantiate (obsticle, new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y + 7f), transform.rotation);
        return;
    }

    if (collision.tag == "ColorChanger") 
    {
        setRandomColor ();
        Destroy (collision.gameObject);
        Instantiate(colorChanger, new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y + 7f), transform.rotation);
        return;
    }

    if (collision.tag != currentColor) {
        Debug.Log ("You Died");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        score = 0;
    }

    if (collision.tag == "Floor") 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
}

void setRandomColor()
{
    int rand = Random.Range (0, 4);

    switch (rand) 
    {
    case 0:
        currentColor = "Blue";
        sr.color = blue;
        break;

    case 1:
        currentColor = "Yellow";
        sr.color = yellow;
        break;

    case 2:
        currentColor = "Pink";
        sr.color = pink;
        break;

    case 3:
        currentColor = "Purple";
        sr.color = purple;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing a HighScore in Unity C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089829/storing-a-highscore-in-unity-c-sharp)

Comment: not a duplicate! the link you post the question is about pop up highscore messeges! not what i want

Comment: you must be having a bad day

Comment: Just look at the answers given in the linked post. You will have examples about how to store and retrieve highscore using PlayerPrefs....

Comment: ok, just thought stack overflow was a place for help and find answers! why direct me away from here! is this not what stack overflow is for?

Comment: Here is an other link : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/644911/how-do-i-store-highscore-locally-c-simple.html

Comment: I've given you : a link to a similar question on StackOverflow, an official tutorial and a question on the official "answers platform" of Unity to prove you have not made any efforts to find a solution by yourself, which is the .... [1st advice on the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if cant help and only link to other places it shows you obviously do not know how to help! i will wait real developers that know and can maybe be of help rather than someone that can only post links!

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"

Comment: How rude some people on here can be on people looking for help is sad to see and not needed. David stated he is still finding his feet with development so to jump on his back there is no need. As soon as i get home i will help you with this @DavidMarsh bear with me

Comment: Thank you james i appreciate it

Comment: Solved it now thanks to @Shadowtail but greatful for your willing to help james :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with incrementing the score. If you want to save a high score and have it persist across games, I recommend making a .txt file in your Assets folder, and writing the score to it if it's greater than what's in the file. I haven't tested it because I'm on my phone but something like this should work:

```
using System.IO;

public Text highScoreText;

void Start() {
    highScoreText.text = File.ReadAllText(TEXTFILEPATH);
}

if (collision.tag != currentColor) {
    Debug.Log ("You Died");

    if (File.Exists(TEXTFILEPATH) {
        int highScore = int.TryParse(File.ReadAllText(TEXTFILEPATH);
        if(score > highScore) {
            File.WriteAllText(TEXTFILEPATH, score.ToString());
        }
    else {
        File.WriteAllText(TEXTFILEPATH, score.ToString());
    }
    }
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
score = 0;
}
```

Comment: interesting! will certainly give it a shot and get back to you